# spotify api authorization issue

Tags: rest, postman, spotify

I have been quite lost in the authorization steps in spotify api

I need to make a request that resembles this in Postman:

```
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4ZjAw...WY0MzE=" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

with headers containing client_id and client_secret (api credentials)

here's how I made the request:
[image]

[image]

those were done according to authorization flow (fourth one in their authorization guide-(implicit grant flow (client credentials flow))
last one in this page:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification for [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow), the header you need to send is like so:

```
Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
```

So you need to Base64 encode the following string  `client id`, `:` and `client secret` together like the following (using the full values):

`ba2a...3973:4f1c...c99d`

Then add `Basic` before this and send this as an `Authorization` Header not individual **client_id** and **client_secret** headers.